# How to run script only by press the button in tkinter/python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hope it is basic question, I got this code:

```
from final3 import mainrun3
from final4 import mainrun4

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def x():
    run1 = mainrun3()

def y():
    run2 = mainrun4()

click_button = Button(root, text='x', width=8, command=x)
click_button.pack()
click_button = Button(root, text='y', width=8, command=y)
click_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How to run imported script only when I click the button? Currently, scripts run with running the Tkinter script.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `final3 ` and `final4`, your claim of "Currently, scripts run with running the Tkinter script" does not appear to possible.

Comment: @martineau Right! I see. So the case is now, how to run scripts (in this thread final3.py and final4.py) without importing script by using buttons in tkinter? Do you have any idea?

Comment: What you have might work if you just changed the two `command=` arguments to directly reference `mainrun3` and `mainrun4` (and get rid of the `x()` and `y()` functions). Example: `Button(root, text='x', width=8, command=mainrun3)`

Comment: Currently solved by subprocess. Anyway, thank you for your help @martineau